# How can be expressed this Access Query to SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a database in access but recently moved to SQL server, and I have modified almost all queries but this one :

```
UPDATE Articulos_Auditoria 
INNER JOIN Auditoria ON Articulos_Auditoria.CUD = Auditoria.CUD 
SET Articulos_Auditoria.Cortado = 'True' 
WHERE 
   (((CAST([Fecha] AS DATE)) = CAST(@Fecha AS DATE)) 
    AND ((Auditoria.Terminal) = @term))
```

I am trying to convert it to SQL Server (since I changed `DateValue` to a `CAST`) but intellisense gives me a syntax error near 'INNER'

Can anyone give me some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors:

1. You need to define the `SET` after the `UPDATE TableName`
2. You need to define a `FROM` clause

   ```
   UPDATE Articulos_Auditoria 
          SET Cortado = 'True'
   FROM   Articulos_Auditoria 
          INNER JOIN Auditoria 
              ON Articulos_Auditoria.CUD = Auditoria.CUD 
   WHERE  CAST([Fecha] as date)=CAST(@Fecha as date) 
          AND Auditoria.Terminal=@term
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `from` clause and table aliases:

```
UPDATE aa
    SET Cortado = 'True'
    FROM Articulos_Auditoria aa INNER JOIN
         Auditoria a
         ON aa.CUD = a.CUD 
    WHERE CAST([Fecha] as date) = CAST(@Fecha as date) AND (a.Terminal = @term)
```

Comment: I will admit i was not aware of that syntax. I was always using the name of the table i am updating both in the `UPDATE` and the `FROM`.

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos . . . That is dangerous.  If you introduce aliases into the `from` clause, then you might end up breaking the query.  I wish SQL Server only allowed a table name when there is no `from` clause.

Comment: Sorry, i may not understand... Isn't your suggestion here using aliases?

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos . . . Yes.  I don't like the use of a table name with a `from` clause.

Comment: hehe...for a moment i thought your comment was against the use of aliases in this scenario. (i am not a native English speaking person).